# How to move cursor and click item using firefox addon script like imacros

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, imacros

I do believe there is no way to use simple javascript to move mouse and click item/url. I have searched a lot about this, and most answer I found, it's not possible for security reason.

But How about using firefox addon script? I do believe it's possible, because imacros does that, even better they can record and replay it.

But I can find how they do that, Can anybody give me some clue how to move mouse cursor using addon script?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that that doesn't involve the headache of making sure that everything is positioned exactly correctly is using [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/).  Selenium provides a very robust browser automation toolkit, and the IDE version is fairly easy to use although it may require some tweaking.  You can download the Firefox plugin [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/), under Selenium IDE.